# Derby JDBC Driver not found when a War is deployed on Payara Micro

Tags: maven, java-8, derby, payara-micro

I am trying to run the example as per the Link below, step by step:

https://dzone.com/articles/easy-java-ee-microservices-with-payara-micro

The example makes use of Apache Derby DB that I have included in Maven POM and also gets bundled in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the War file.

However, when I try to run the application with command

```
sudo java -jar payara-micro-5.2020.4.jar --deploy <path to>/SampleService-1.0.war
```

I get the following error:

````
javax.resource.ResourceException: The driver could not be loaded: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver```
````

Answer (score 1):

1. It may be a class loading order problem. Check out https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.201/documentation/payara-server/classloading.html
2. Derby has been removed starting from version 5.201. Check out https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.4/documentation/payara-micro/h2/h2.html
   Use the exact same versions in your example tutorial or use H2 instead of Derby.
3. Finally check out "Adding Third-Party JARs to a Micro Instance" https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.201/documentation/payara-micro/adding-jars.html

Comment: You can download Derby from the Apache website at http://db.apache.org/derby